# WPF - Making a progressbar button and having it properly size

Tags: c#, wpf, button, progress-bar

I am trying to make a button in WPF that will show progress but still have its button text visible.

I tried adding a `Grid` as a child to the button and adding a `ProgressBar` and `Label` to the grid, thinking the `Grid` will fill the button and using `VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` on the progress bar and label will get me, basically, a clickable progress bar, that can show progress and have a label on top of it. However, I'm having problem with the sizing.

This is my XAML:

```
        <Button Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="100" MinHeight="25" Margin="3">
            <Grid>
                <ProgressBar Value="10" Maximum="20" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                <Label Content="asd2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </Button>
```

This is what I see:

[image: Bad button]

If I change to explicit sizing:

```
        <Button Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="100" MinHeight="25" Margin="3">
            <Grid>
                <ProgressBar Value="10" Maximum="20" Width="100" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                <Label Content="asd2" Width="100" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </Button>
```

I get this:

[image: Better button, but still bad]

Which, visually, is an improvement, but XAML-programatically is worse, since I want the button to resize with the window, if the user can't see it well or something like that. Also, visually - I don't like that little border between the actual button and the start of the progressbar and I've tried setting both "padding" and "margin" to 0, it's not from that.

What I'd like to see - the progress bar taking up ALL the space of the button and the label text staying centered both vertically and horizontally, with respect to the total size of the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your `<Grid>` inside of a `ControlTemplate` and override your `<Button.Template>`:

```
        <Button Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="100" MinHeight="25" Margin="3">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid>
                        <ProgressBar Value="10" Maximum="20" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                        <Label Content="asd2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>            
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>
```

What you were doing before is putting your `<Grid>` inside of the Button's `ContentTemplate`, not its `Template`.  The problem with the `ContentTemplate` is that it has some of the default button's styling, such as the little border you don't like.  By moving it to the Button's overall Template, you're saying I don't care about how the default button looks, I want it to look exactly like THIS.

What it can look like:

[image]

What it can look like if you resize the window:

[image]